# Address Matching for reports

Tags: architecture

Does anyone here have a solution to address matching - given that people can type almost whatever the heck their fingers hit.

Example

```
123 Main Street
123 Main St
123 S. Main St.
123 South Main
```

This becomes a problem when they all actually refer to the same physical location and I want to run a report for all things at this location.

Yes, we have tried to reduce this issue of confusion by implementing "location codes" (like store#123) but since these are strings, you may run into fat-finger issues still. OR in our worst nightmare - take automated feeds from someplace who doesn't use or care about our "location codes".

If you have a similar problem - how did you solve it? Keep in mind the automated entry or import of data - so simply "prompting with UI" of close doesn't really solve my problem.

We are thinking some parent child relation, or an array of associated records.... But we don't really want to re-invent the wheel if this problem has been solved better elsewhere.

ANY suggestions are greatly appreciated.

This is a general question about solutions not code specific. If this is the wrong place to ask this question, please suggest were is the 'correct' place to ask such a question.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse these on input from the report and format them before saving.

Every single time I've been required to ensure addresses are valid and consistent we've always had an external API that handles it. Essentially you give the API the address and it gives you back a formatted standardized version of the address that is recognized by the relevant postal systems if the address is valid.

These API's have a prices attached for example: https://smartystreets.com is the first hit when I google "address validation"